# how to run web application with only doPost()?

Tags: java, web, web-applications

```
`enter code here`@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
    String x = req.getParameter("x");
    String y = req.getParameter("y");
    String op = req.getParameter("op");
    try (PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter()) {
        writer.write("sd");
    }
}
```

Can I run web application with only doPost method() in Servlet?i made and it want doGet method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, you can do it. Given below is an example:

**TestDoPost.java:**

```
package servlets;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/TestDoPost")
public class TestDoPost extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public TestDoPost() {
        super();
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
        response.getWriter().write("Success!");
    }
}
```

**NewFile.html:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="TestDoPost" method="post">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Deploy the application and click the `Submit` button in the HTML file. Given below is the result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Omg you share all information I need and I did not see yet..Thankss a lot. Actually, I was not hoping to get answer,but you help me. Thanks a lot) @Arwind Kumar Avinash